# oracle sql aggregate function with default values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as follows: I want to get the count for yes and NO for each id.

counterTb:

```
id  taxPin  Status
1   123     Y
1   234     Y
1   345     Y
1   456     N
1   567     N
2   678     Y
2   789     Y
2   890     null
2   901     N
1   100     null
```

My output should like like below for a selected id: say example id = 1;

Output

```
id Status   count
1   YES     3
1   NO      2
```

If there are no values ,
say for id = 3

```
   id Status    count
    3   YES     0
    3   NO      0
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Do you need to show the count even when it's zero? This is slightly more subtle than it may seem.

Comment: @mathguy yes I want to show the count even when yes count is 0 and No count is 0. Can you hep with that please?

Answer (score 1):

Edit to include 0's.

```
SELECT
  id_list.id,
  status_list.status,
  COUNT(counterTb.id)
FROM
(
  SELECT 3 AS id FROM dual
)
  id_list
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT 'YES' AS status FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'NO'  AS status FROM dual
)
  status_list
LEFT JOIN
  counterTb
    ON  counterTb.id     = id_list.id
    AND counterTb.status = status_list.status
GROUP BY
  id_list.id,
  status_list.status
ORDER BY
  id_list.id,
  status_list.status DESC
```

Comment: This will also show the count of null status, which presumably should not be shown. That is not hard to fix; the trick is to think about it in the first place.

Comment: @mathguy i have to show the yes and No even when they are 0. Please see my question updated

Comment: The updated version is closer to what the OP needs. Of course, the `id_list` subquery should not select a hard-coded value from `dual`, but instead it should select distinct `id` from the base table (or select `id` from a separate table where `id` is primary key). Also, the OP's sample data uses `'Y'` and `'N'`; he did request `'Yes'` and `'No'` for the output, but the query needs to work with the existing data. Other than that, partitioned outer join does away with the first pass through the data (the `id_list` subquery); it is the standard data densification feature of outer joins.

Comment: @mathguy In the current form of the question, there are no source rows for id 3, not even with a NULL status. Yet, the OP wants 0's for id 3 in the output. This achieves that (except for the Y / N vs YES / NO part). As I'm on my phone and the OP keeps changing, I'm disinclined to make any further edits.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is what you need. Notice the "helper" inline view, creating the 'Y' and 'N' values as a separate, small table, and the ***partitioned*** outer join (partitioned by `id`) to ensure that every `id` present in the input table appears in the output, with both the `Y` and the `N` counts. Note the additional test cases I put in the `with` clause (which is there strictly for testing, it is not part of the solution - remove it and apply the query to your existing table, using the actual table and column names). Especially `id = 3` needs to be considered carefully - in other ways of writing the query, that `id` will not appear at all in the output.

```
with
  counterTb (id, taxPin, Status) as (
    select 1, 123, 'Y'  from dual union all
    select 1, 234, 'Y'  from dual union all
    select 1, 345, 'Y'  from dual union all
    select 1, 456, 'N'  from dual union all
    select 1, 567, 'N'  from dual union all
    select 2, 678, 'Y'  from dual union all
    select 2, 789, 'Y'  from dual union all
    select 2, 890, null from dual union all
    select 2, 901, 'N'  from dual union all
    select 1, 100, null from dual union all
    select 3, 323, null from dual union all
    select 4, 422, 'N'  from dual union all
    select 4, 433, 'N'  from dual
  )
select c.id, h.status, count(c.status) as yn_count
from   (select 'Y' as status from dual union all select 'N' from dual) h
           left outer join
       counterTb c
           partition by (c.id)
           on h.status = c.status
group  by c.id, h.status
having h.status in ('Y', 'N')
order  by id, status desc
;
```

Output:

```
ID STATUS YN_COUNT
-- ------ --------
 1 Y             3
 1 N             2
 2 Y             2
 2 N             1
 3 Y             0
 3 N             0
 4 Y             0
 4 N             2
```

Comment: thank a lot. CAn you look at this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67307641/sql-with-aggreate-and-union

Comment: can you hep with this