# join with lookup and groupby

Tags: sql, oracle

i have 2 tables like below:

```
lk_premier:
code descr
P    Premier
N    Non Premier
```

Case:

```
id  taxPin  
1   123     
2   789  
3   090
```

Status:

```
id voting_status premier
1   5               P
1   5               P
1   5               P
2   5               P
2   5               N
2   5               null
3   5               null
3   5               null
3   5               null
3   5               null
3   5               null
```

I used the below sql

```
select
        decode(premier,
        'P',
        'PREMIER',
        'N',
        'NON PREMIER') as caseStatus,
        count(*) as count   
    from
        status s,
        case c
    where
        c.id = s.id 
        and c.id = 1  
        and s.voting_status = 5  
    group by
        premier
```

I want to join the lk_premier table, so my output looks like for id=2,

```
caseStatus  count
PREMIER     1
NON PREMIER 1
```

for id = 3

```
caseStatus  count
PREMIER     0
NON PREMIER 0
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the normal behaviour when you are doing aggregates.

But you could solve this by introducing a virtual table for the list of caseStatus values.

```
(
SELECT 'P' as caseStatus FROM DUAL
UNION 
SELECT 'N' as caseStatus FROM DUAL
)
```

Then you can do a join and aggregate against this table and you should be able to get the output you want